# Four table join django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

**Intro**

Relatively new to django, curious how to do a 4-way join for my specific use-case using the ORM.

**Django Models**

```
class Foo( models.Model ):
  attr1 = ...

class Bar( models.Model ):
  foo = models.ForeignKey ( Foo )
  attr2 = ...

class BarOneToOne( models.Model ):
  bar = models.ForeignKey ( Bar ) 
  attr3 = ...

class BarManyToOne( models.Model ):
  bar = models.ForeignKey ( Bar )
  attr4 = ...
```

**The Problem**

Want a list of the `BarManyToOne` with the associated `BarOneToOne`, `Bar`, and `Foo` data.  Want to filter that based on `Foo` ids.

**Example**

Data:

```
Foo                     Bar
--------------        -----------------------
| id | attr1 |        | id | attr2 | foo_id |
--------------        -----------------------
  1    apple           101   larry      1
  2    orange          102   bob        2
  3    pear            103   sue        3
  4    grape           104   laura      1
                       105   nancy      4

BarOneToOne            BarManyToOne
------------------     --------------------
| bar_id | attr3 |     | bar_id |  attr4  |
------------------     --------------------
   101      dog           101     cinnamon
   103      mouse         104     thyme
   104      cat           103     garlic
                          104     sea salt
                          101     chili powder
                          103     paprika
```

Desired result:

```
 --------------------------------------
 | apple | larry | dog |   cinnamon   |
 --------------------------------------
 | apple | laura | cat |    thyme     |
 --------------------------------------
 | apple | laura | cat |   sea salt   |
 --------------------------------------
 | apple | larry | dog | chili powder |
 --------------------------------------
```

**SQL Equivalent**

```
SELECT f.attr1, b.attr2, bmto.attr3, bmtoa.attr4
FROM foo f, bar b, bar_one_to_one boto, bar_many_to_one bmto
WHERE bmto.bar_id = boto.bar_id AND b.id = bmto.bar_id
AND b.foo_id = f.id AND f.id = ?;
```

**Misc**

So far I've seen `select_related` in the docs, which feels very useful.  Also the __ approach.  Feels like the pieces are here, but haven't been able to put it all together just yet.

In terms of performance/size, the Foo, Bar, and BarOneToOne tables will all be small (under 500 rows each, even likely under 100 rows each).  The BarManyToOne table will be larger.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set related_names for your models depending on your frame of reference. There are plenty of ways to do this, but for this purpose, I will use the `BarManyToOne` table as the main table.

```
class Foo( models.Model ):
    attr1 = ...

class Bar( models.Model ):
    foo = models.ForeignKey ( Foo, related_name='foo_bars')
    attr2 = ...

class BarOneToOne( models.Model ):
    bar = models.ForeignKey ( Bar, related_name='bar_baronetoones' ) 
    attr3 = ...

class BarManyToOne( models.Model ):
    bar = models.ForeignKey ( Bar, related_name='bar_barmanytoones' )
    attr4 = ...
```

With the model setup shown above, this will be the code you will need to invoke to get the SQL query equivalent.

```
BarManyToOne.objects.all().select_related(
    'bar',                             # Joins the three other tables
    'bar__foo',                        # with BarManyToOne serving as
    'bar__bar_baronetoones'            # the main table
).filter(                              # Your (non join condition) WHERE clauses
    bar__foo_id=<your value here>      # f.id = ?
).values(                              # The columns you want
    'bar__foo__attr1',                 # f.attr1
    'bar__attr2',                      # b.attr2
    'bar__bar_baronetoones__attr3',    # boto.attr3
    'attr4'                            # bmto.attr4
)
```

You will need to read up on [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), [the making queries section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/), and [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F).

Comment: Will give it a whirl tomorrow, but looks like just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I edited the arguments to filter(). I did not notice it at first, but upon second look, the additional WHERE conditions are JOIN conditions that should already be automatically included when doing select_related().